# How to configure different Kafka Brokers/endpoints for different test environments?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, automated-tests, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka in my integration tests wherein it publishes to different topics and my tests reads from them and validates. Now, I have created a class with different Kafka constants/endpoints, but these constants vary on different environments; say for e.g - ST, SIT, etc. 
How do I configure these constants as per environment so that in pipeline whichever environment am running my tests on it picks up the right constants/endpoints.

It currently looks like below, please guide how to configure on various environments.

```
package Kafka;

//ST

public interface KafkaConst {

public static String KAFKA_BROKERS = "https://10.156.192.120:1211";

public static Integer MESSAGE_COUNT=10;

public static String INBOUND_TOPIC_NAME="publish.st"

public static String GROUP_ID_CONFIG="consumerGroup1";

public static String SCHEMA_REGISTRY = "http://10.156.192.71:1212";

public static Integer MAX_NO_MESSAGE_FOUND_COUNT=10;

public static String OFFSET_RESET_LATEST="latest";

public static String OFFSET_RESET_EARLIER="earliest";

public static Integer MAX_POLL_RECORDS=1000; 

public static String KAFKA_File="src/test/resources/TransformedXML/";

}
```

//SIT

```
public interface KafkaConst {

public static String KAFKA_BROKERS = "https://10.156.165.120:1211";

public static Integer MESSAGE_COUNT=10;

public static String INBOUND_TOPIC_NAME="publish.sit"

public static String GROUP_ID_CONFIG="consumerGroup1";

public static String SCHEMA_REGISTRY = "http://10.156.165.71:1212";

public static Integer MAX_NO_MESSAGE_FOUND_COUNT=10;

public static String OFFSET_RESET_LATEST="latest";

public static String OFFSET_RESET_EARLIER="earliest";

public static Integer MAX_POLL_RECORDS=1000; 

public static String KAFKA_File="src/test/resources/TransformedXML/";

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest getting away from hardcoded values and use environment variables. Most of the CI/CD tools support injecting environment variables in the pipeline runtime, while in your code you take those values not from hardcoded classes but from environment variables.

I see that you've added the `spring-kafka` tag... in a Spring app, it's super easy to get values from environment variables. You can either use the `@Value` annotation or the `@ConfigurationProperties` one. There are tons of examples on the internet for both.

Comment: Or use `TestContainers` / `EmbeddedKafka` to run "integration tests"

Answer (score 1):

Use [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-conditional) to select which properties apply in each environment.

> It is often useful to conditionally enable or disable a complete `@Configuration` class or even individual `@Bean methods`, based on some arbitrary system state. One common example of this is to use the `@Profile` annotation to activate beans only when a specific profile has been enabled in the Spring Environment (see Bean Definition Profiles for details).